# How to Create a function with the same name as Base Class in Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a requirement as below ex:

```
class Base 
{

public:
Base() { cout << "Base Class Constructor";}
virtual ~Base() { cout << "Base Class Destructor";}
};

class Der : public Base
{
public:
    Der() { cout << "Der Class Constructor";}
    ~Der() { cout << "Der Class Destructor";}
    void Base() {cout << "Der Class function";}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    Base *ptr = new Der();
    ptr->Base(); // throwing error here - "Invalid use of class Base". My intention is to call Der::Base() function. 
    return 1;
}
```

Please any one suggest me the way to call Function "void Base()" declared in the Der class via Base pointer pointed to a Der object.

IDE: Qt Creator
OS: Ubuntu 10.10
Compiler: GCC (X86)

Answer (score 1):

Having a member function with the same name as the base class is extremely poor taste and error prone (making the code unreadable for humans). Are you sure you cannot avoid that??

<sup>A common convention is to have class names starting with upper-case letters, and member functions in lower cases. If you follow that convention, you won't be hurt like you are!</sup>

If you really insist, you might try

```
   (static_cast<Der*>(ptr))->Base();
```

A safer way could be to code something like

```
  { Der* derptr = dynamic_cast<Der*>(ptr);
    if (derptr) 
       derptr->Base(); 
  }
```

But really, **you should avoid coding such non-sense**. Your code is becoming unreadable, and that would hurt even you in a few weeks...

Don't forget to compile your code with `g++ -Wall -g` (improving it till you get no compilation warnings) and to use the `gdb` debugger to debug it. Don't forget to end your output statements with `<< endl`.

<sup>There are other mistakes in your code. It does not compile, even with `main` kept empty</sup>

Comment: But I don't think it solves your misunderstanding... You really really should avoid that. And if it is a homework, it merits a bad grade because of that misunderstanding, and poor coding conventions (making your code unreadable, even to your teacher).

Comment: Thanks again. I do really follow the coding conventions, so that these kind of situations i never meet.

Comment: Why do you have to name a *member function* with the *same name* `Base` as the *super-class*? This is **very confusing**.